# Can a class property/field be of anonymous type in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

As in:

```
public class MyClass {

  private static var MyProp = new {item1 = "a", item2 = "b"};

}
```

Note: The above doesn't compile nor work (the var cannot be used there), it's only to show my point.

**Update**: Just to clarify the question, I had already tried using

```
private static dynamic MyProp = new {item1 = "a", item2 = "b"};
```

and this works, but it doesn't generate intellisense because of the dynamic typing. I am aware that anonymous typing is just a compiler trick, so I hoped I could use this trick to my advantage by declaring a structured field without having to declare a class beforehand (mainly because there's only going to be one instance of this particular kind of field). I can see now that it's not possible, but I'm not sure why that is. If the compiler is simply generating an implicit type for an anonymous object, it should be fairly simply to have the compiler generate this implicit type for a field.

Comment: `MyProp` is not a property, it's a field.

Comment: @Greg : There, I fixed it for Diego (and you) :P

Comment: @Andrew - I feel so relieved, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, any member should be a explicitly typed.

You might go for dynamic type to give your member a chance to be evaluated at runtime though.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you could be asking one or two questions so I'll try and address them both.

**Can a class field be strongly typed to an anonymous type**

No.  Anonymous type names cannot be stated in C# code (hence anonymous).  The only way to statically type them is

1. Generic type inferencee
2. Use of the `var` keyword

Neither of these are applicable to the field of a type.

**Can a class field be initialized with an anonymous type expression?**

Yes.  The field just needs to be declared to a type compatible with anonymous types: `object` for example

```
public class MyClass { 
  private static object MyProp = new {item1 = "a", item2 = "b"}; 
}
```

Comment: Err...so the answer is not "yes", but "no"?

Comment: @Adam the answer is the question is ambiguous :)  I'll try to make my answer less so

Comment: Yes... Both object and dynamic does not give an anonymous member. So Answer should be no.

Comment: Curious; If you assign an anonymous type to an `object`, how do you cast it to get the real type?

Comment: @abhishek: `object` is certainly a type.

Comment: @Adam, sorry, I mistakenly wrote that. I meant something else. So edited.

Comment: I think you might go for either object or dynamic, but in both the cases you need to employ reflection as the type is missing to you.

Comment: If you use object as the field's type, you lose any ability to access the 2 properties of that type without reflection (which defeats the whole purpose of this)

Comment: @Diego, When i read the question I couldn't tell which scenario you were getting at and tried to offer the most complete answer.  There are tricks othre than reflection to get at an anonymous types values from `object` but they're hacky IMHO.  So yes it does rendere the object mostly less than useful.  If you need a field the best path is to use a defined type or tuple.

Answer (score 6):

In C# 7 you can finally do this:

```
private (string Login, string Password) _credentials = (Login: "123", Password: "123");
```

Comment: A `ValueTuple` is nothing like an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`Tuple<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instead?

```
public class MyClass {

  private static Tuple<string, string> MyProp = Tuple.Create("a", "b");

}
```

Comment: I was about to provide this exact code block myself. Explicitly statically typed, and you don't have to manually construct a new type. I really hope this gets upvoted ahead of those silly "dynamic" solutions.

Comment: Of course, now that your answer was sniped that is probably unlikely.

Comment: Hehe, oh well.  It's not necessarily clear anyway from the question that a Tuple would be a good solution.  The example code only has fields "item1" and "item2", but perhaps the real code has more logical names, which would be lost by using a Tuple.  Since this is a private field a Tuple is probably ok, but if this were a public field I'd probably say a better idea is to define a specific type to store this data, even though it's a bit more coding.

Comment: Exactly, the idea is to have a static constant field that is structured, and could have several levels of nesting anonymous components.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C# 4, look into the dynamic keyword.

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
  private static dynamic MyProp = new {item1 = "a", item2 = "b"}; 
}
```

However, as soon as you do this you lose any sort of type-safety and handy compiler checks.

Comment: That's what I did, but I lost intellisense on the object's properties. I'd like to do it so that intellisense can aid people using my class.

Answer (score 0):

No, anonymous types cannot be exposed outside of their declaring function as anything other than `object`. While the anonymous type is just syntactical sugar and does, in fact, create a concrete type, this type is never known (nor available) to the developer, and thus can't be used.

Comment: You say "never known" and "can't be used," but aren't you discounting reflection and `dynamic`? (Not that I'm encouraging the practice, mind you.)

Comment: @Anthony: No, neither of those allow the developer (as in, the person writing the code) to "know" the type. You can certainly call `GetType()` on the object, but that is a runtime-only operation. Nor is `dynamic` a solution.

Comment: I would say the type can be known to the developer (as LINQ demonstrates) in generic methods. You could even have a field for the anonymous type in a generic class. Of course, use of that field will be quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

An property (or field) of **a named class** can't have an anonymous type, because such a type can't be referred to in code. **However**, an anonymous type *can* contain properties of anonymous type:

```
var myObj = new
{
    Foo = new { Name = "Joe", Age = 20 }
};
```

But such a construct has no practical use outside the local scope...

Answer (score -1):

Nope, but here's an ugly workaround for compatibility with intellisense.

```
public class Strings {

    public static Tags tags = new Tags();

    public class Tags {
        public string myCoolTag1 = "Foo";
        public string myCoolTag2 = "Bar";
    }
}
```

To consume:

```
DoCoolThingy(Strings.tags.myCoolTag1);
```