# Handle Linq queries outputs

Tags: c#, linq

I've been struggling for the last 3 days on that topic.
I'm  sure i'm doing something wrong but there, i need help.

During the load of a form, i'm doing a Linq query (on a global dataset) to populate fields on that form. As i want to be able to change the views of the form, i want queries that will make the data available in a specific format (to avoid having to query every now on then (the dataset is 20,000 lines)).
so i came up with that first queries :

```
   var results =
        from row in Globals.ds.Tables["Song"].AsEnumerable()
        group row by (row.Field<int>("year"), row.Field<int>("rating")) into grp
        orderby grp.Key
        select new
        {
            year = grp.Key.Item1,
            conte = grp.ToList().Count,
            rating = grp.Key.Item2,
            duree = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("duree"))
        };
```

It works and i'm pasting the result in the following screenshot (conte is the count)

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVhfj.png)

1 have 2 issues :

1/ I really dont know how to handle that result : i would like to filter for a specific year and list all the subsequent ratings (i have from 1 to 6 per year). I tried the .ToList() but it only helped to get the count. The CopyToDataTable is not available for the query.

2/ i have buttons in the form that will need to access to that query, yet the var result is only available in the load and i can't manage to declare it at the class level.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can put a set of parenthesis around entire query and the use a where : (query).Where(x => year == 1972).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So:

1. Your first point have been answered by @jdweng
   It is possible to use [`LinQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) also for collections (ex. `List`), not only Db queries.
2. The reason is that the result of the query is an anonymous type, and [it can't be declared outside local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982245/12730306). You must create a new class with the same structure.

```cs
public class MyResultClass
{
    public int year;
    public int conte;
    public int rating;
    public int duree;
}
```

Define your field:

```cs
List<MyResultClass> data;
```

And then use both:

```cs
var result =
    from row in Globals.ds.Tables["Song"].AsEnumerable()
    group row by (row.Field<int>("year"), row.Field<int>("rating")) into grp
    orderby grp.Key
    select new MyResultClass
    {
        year = grp.Key.Item1,
        conte = grp.ToList().Count,
        rating = grp.Key.Item2,
        duree = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("duree"))
    };
data = result.ToList();
```

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: You were really helpful ! thank you very much :)
Both you and jdweng of course :)